# QGIS - export a project with dependencies

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I was wandering if there was a way to save a specific project with all layers as dependent files to make it easy to share with collaborators.

for example, create a zipped or non-zipped folder containing the same structure as the project :

```
Root_folder/
my_project.qgs
    \____________myfolder
                     \___Layer 1
                     \___Layer 2
                     \___Layer 3
    \____________myfolder2
                     \___Layer 4
                     \___Layer 5
                     \___Layer 6
    \____________myfolder3
                     \________myfolder4
                                     \___Layer 6
                                     \___Layer 7
                     \___Layer 8
```

If it does not exists, would it be tricky to develop regarding the current API ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at the [QConsolidate plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qconsolidate/). You can install it from Plugin Installer. If it does not provide a complete solution for your need, look to its code for examples on crafting your solution with the API. Creating a custom directory structure for the layers will probably need to be added.

Another portable file-based solution is to use a [Spatialite database](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/). It can handle vector and raster formats, and is natively supported in QGIS's new Database Manager.

Comment: I didn't know that plugin. That would do the trick for the moment. Many thanks