# Reprojecting all layers in GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ogr2ogr, geopackage

In QGIS we can package all the layers using the "Package layers" tool but is there a way to also reproject all the component layers within the tool or using ogr2ogr?

We have:

```
processing.run("native:package", {'LAYERS':['Layer List],
                                  'OUTPUT':'GIS_20210531.gpkg',
                                  'OVERWRITE':False,
                                  'SAVE_STYLES':True})
```

Can we add something to this code like `for /r %f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "%~dpnf_4326.shp" -s_srs EPSG:4283 -t_srs EPSG:4326 "%f" -dsco SHAPE_RESTORE_SHX=YES 1` or the examples in [Is there any way to reproject multiple layers in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32142/is-there-any-way-to-reproject-multiple-layers-in-qgis)

Looking at https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html I can't see any examples for reprojection.

All inputs are vector. I do not want to convert to shp/tab and then reproject and repackage.

Looking for an ogr2ogr or QGIS solution.

Comment: Try `ogr2ogr -f gpkg -t_srs epsg:xxxx new_geopackage.gpkg old_geopackage.gpkg`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ogr2ogr can convert with one run all the tables that are given in the command as a list

`...input.gpkg layer1 layer2 layer 3`

If no layers are given in the command then **all** layers are processed. Layer is an optional parameter as documented in https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html

```
dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name
  ...    [layer [layer ...]]
```

If all ogr2ogr parameters are suitable for all the layers (so no renaming of layers etc.) the whole geopackage can be reprojected with one command

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg -t_srs epsg:xxxx new_geopackage.gpkg old_geopackage.gpkg
```

Comment: I do not know really. Why to use QGIS if you can do the task from the command line?

Comment: The same result can be achieved in QGIS via `Processing Toolbox > GDAL > Vector conversion > Convert format`. Choose your GPKG in source, your destination GPKG as output, and in Advanced Parameter type `-t_srs epsg:xxxx`

Comment: unfortunately the Convert format algorithm does not work on a gpkg with multiple layers, because QGIS creates a wrong ogr2ogr command, here is an example:
`ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" -t_srs epsg: 32633 C: /Users/pigre/Desktop/sabrina/limiti_admin.gpkg C: /Users/pigre/Desktop/sabrina/limiti_admin.gpkg RipGeo01012021_WGS84`

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/43701

Comment: bug fixed in 3.24 : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/45955