# Sharing a QGIS project

Tags: qgis

Is there a simple way to save a QGIS project and all associated files to a zip folder so that another person could unzip the folder and open the project?

Or is there a better way to share a project with another person?

Comment: look at [QGIS - export a project with dependencies](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29195/qgis-export-a-project-with-dependencies)

Comment: No simple way, this is one of those painful ESRI "features" that QGIS decided to support.  You can have in-memory layers for vectors, but it's not intended for self-contained project files afaik. FWIW, Manifold's project files operate standalone by default, it's hard to imagine living without it once you've used it.

Comment: Personally I prefer just zipping all the necessary files. Normally, I create a folder which contains the project file and other folders, each of which contain shapefiles. I haven't had any complaints from others that I gave the data to :)

Comment: In addition to QConsolidate there is also the 'relocator' plug-in.

Comment: Thanks all for the guidance on this (don't yet know how to reply to all the commenters at once, so hope you all see it).  As a beginner, I'll go with zipping all the files into a folder and e-mailing that to my co-workers.